# Get count of documents from other specific collection flutter firebase

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-test

I have an application in which I want to get the count of all documents from the specific collection.
Here is the Screenshot of my Firebase Firestore
[image]

I want to get access to all the documents in the Article collection While Staying in the Course Collection I am using ListView Builder
I followed different lectures but not working.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
Firestore.instance.collection('YOUR_COLLECTION_NAME_HERE').snapshots().length.toString();
```

Comment: The Article collection is a sub-collection of the Course collection. Please update your answer to acciunt for this (I imagine something along the lines of replacing `'Article'` with something like `'Course/${courseId}/Article'`)

Comment: Actually thing is that I want to show the length in each card and every card has different doucments

Comment: You should then use a [CollectionGroup query](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/FirebaseFirestore/collectionGroup.html), but see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The recommended approach for counting the number of documents in one or more collections is to use some [counters](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/counters).

Querying one or more collection(s) and getting the size of the snapshot(s) each time you want to get the number of docs can incur some high costs, since, by querying all docs of a collection **it costs one read per document**.

If your collections contain a lot of docs and you want to frequently display these figures (number of docs) it can sum up quite fast.

---

Depending on your security rules (i.e. your access rights) you would update the counters from the client/frontend (e.g. only trusted users can update the Courses and Articles and there is no risk they write wrong values for the counters) or from the backend with a Cloud Function (end users cannot modify the counters).

Comment: Hello @zainishfaq, did you have time to loo at the proposed solution?